# How to create a deep link push notification with Pinpoint?

Tags: aws-pinpoint

I am sending APNS push notifications to my app using the Pinpoint JS SDK. I'm trying to enable sending a deep link to open a specific page of the app when the user taps the notification.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html#sendUsersMessages-property) I should be passing `Action: "DEEP_LINK"` however it doesn't say where to specify my link. There is a `Url` attribute, but that is labeled expressly for use with `Action: "URL"`, not `DEEP_LINK`.

Where do I configure the deep link for push notification?

Comment: Did you found out the solution to this question?

Comment: I did not but haven’t had a chance to circle back to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it is not stated clearly in the docs, configuring the `DEEP LINK` in the `Url` attribute is the correct way.